# Python - os.rename() - OSError: [WinError 123]

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, syntax-error

```
path='U:\\rmarshall\Work For Staff\\ROB\\_Downloads Folder\\'
file='file.pdf'
newFileName=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_')+row[1]+time.strftime('_%H:%M:%S')+'.pdf'
newFolderLocation='U:\\Company - do not alter\\'

os.rename(path+file,newFolderLocation+newFileName)
```

When I run I get:

```
>>> os.rename(path+file,newFolderLocation+newFileName)

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is 
incorrect: 'U:/Company - do not alter/2014-01-14_COMPANY NAME_13:55:23.pdf'
```

Can anyone see the syntax error?

Comment: I think you have to escape the spaces too, with `\ `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The colon `:` is not allowed in Windows file names.

See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> the error is due to the fact that windows doesn not support charcter
> "" in the names. Your shuld modify this by replacing "\n" with "".

Answer (score -1):

**please check your urls file name in (urls.py) name is correct or not because i was get same issue during my python-Django project . hope my answers is useful for you**.