# Converting WindowsError to OSError in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, cross-platform, windowserror

In the (legacy) code I maintain people are using `WindowsError`. I could go ahead and replace all occurrences with `OSError` but alas the `winerror` attribute is used, happily only in three cases - namely 123:

```
try:
    mtime = int(os.path.getmtime(self._s))
except WindowsError, werr:
        if werr.winerror != 123: raise
        deprint(u'Unable to determine modified time of %s - probably a unicode error' % self._s)
```

740:

```
try:
    popen = subprocess.Popen(args, close_fds=bolt.close_fds)
    if wait: popen.wait()
except UnicodeError:
    self._showUnicodeError()
except WindowsError as werr:
    if werr.winerror != 740:
        self.ShowError(werr)
```

and 32:

```
try:
    patchName.untemp() # calls shutil.move() and os.remove()
except WindowsError, werr:
    while werr.winerror == 32 and self._retry(patchName.temp.s,
                                              patchName.s):
        try:
            patchName.untemp()
        except WindowsError, werr:
            continue
        break
    else:
        raise
```

How am I going to translate these codes to `OSError` ?

I am in python 2.7 so I can't use the nice exceptions introduced in [pep-3151](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/#appendix-a-survey-of-common-errnos)

Here is a [discussion](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/920347) on mapping winerror to the errno module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out winerror and the errno attribute have different values - in good code practices I did not use the magic number but the constants from the errno module. So 32:

```
-            except WindowsError as werr:
-                if werr.winerror == 32:
+            except OSError as werr:
+                if werr.errno == errno.EACCES: # 13
```

For 123 ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21115580/281545)):

```
with open('file', 'w'): pass
newFileName = 'illegal characters: /\\:*?"<>|'
try:
    os.rename('file', newFileName)
except OSError as e: # winerror = 123, errno = 22
    print e
```

so `errno.EINVAL`.

740 was in windows specific code so I left alone.