# How to apply nltk.pos_tag on pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, nltk, part-of-speech

I'm trying to apply pos tagging on one of my tokenized column called "removed" in pyspark dataframe.

I'm trying with

```
nltk.pos_tag(df_removed.select("removed"))
```

But all I get is Value Error: `ValueError: Cannot apply 'in' operator against a column: please use 'contains' in a string column or 'array_contains' function for an array column.`

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is in the error message: the input of `pos_tag` should be a string and you provide a column input. You should apply `pos_tag` on each row of you column, using the function `withColumn`

For example you start by writing:

```py
my_new_df = df_removed.withColumn("removed", nltk.pos_tag(df_removed.removed))
```

You can do also :

```
my_new_df = df_removed.select("removed").rdd.map(lambda x: nltk.pos_tag(x)).toDF()
```

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) you have the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but I have an error that `DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`
`df_removed.select("removed").map(nltk.pos_tag)`

Comment: Could you please tell me what "rdd" is changing in that code? I'm new at pyspark and I would like to understand it.

Comment: And unfortunately this code does not work for me :( I got Py4Java Error

Comment: RDD is a class which allows to perform operations. What is your error exactly?

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 18.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 483, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.

Comment: I see it is the name problem - OSError: [WinError 123]

Comment: Here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115580/python-os-rename-oserror-winerror-123

Comment: Unfortunately this case does not resolve mine - I don't know why my spark reads such a line: `'C:\\C:\\Users\\Olga\\Desktop\\Spark\\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars\\spark-core_2.11-2.4.5.jar'` So it gets two "C:\\"

Comment: Just add all your code. I see you ar on Windows as OS.

Comment: I asked about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059445/how-to-fix-pyspark-oserror-winerror-123

Comment: I updated  the answer with a function more appropriate for string parsing.

Comment: What's (x) in `my_new_df = df_removed.withColumn("removed", nltk.pos_tag(x))`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Corrected. Check also the documentation I posted.

Comment: Hi, I've tried with  `my_new_df = df_removed.select("removed").rdd.map(lambda x: nltk.pos_tag(x)).toDF()`  
but I got:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit`

Comment: Can you display the column `removed` of your DataFrame? I guess it must be a  list. You need a string.

Comment: Now I found it - I just needed to firstly make `lambda x:x[0] ` and then apply pos_tag. Thank you for help!!!! Your answer really help me :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I couldn't have found the error as you I did not know the format of your input.