# os.chdir() not working due to awaiting user input

Tags: python, input, directory

I have a .get() function to accept user input of a path link. Then use the user's input to change directory @ os.chrdir. But running the code gives me error as this:

> os.chdir(bomlist)
> OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ''

Anyway of working around this problem?

Here is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk , os
entry1 = tk.Entry(top, bd=5, width = 40)
bomlist = entry1.get()
os.chdir(bomlist) #error here
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx', data_only= True)
```

Comment: Put `print(repr(bomlist))` before the `os.chdir()` command to see what the result is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - os.rename() - OSError: \[WinError 123\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115580/python-os-rename-oserror-winerror-123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using tkinter then I would recommend opening the file using the
`from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename`

So your code should be

```
path = askopenfilename()
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only= True)
```

It you want to trigger the opening function you can use a button so when the user clicks a button only then the dialog box pops up